# Make gcc put relative filenames in debug information

Tags: debugging, gcc, cmake, debug-symbols

The project I'm compiling uses CMake, which [loves absolute pathnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008642/ccache-and-absolute-path).

When I compile with debugging information enabled, gcc puts those long names into `.debug_str` sections, which is bad for debugging. I'd like to have short relative-to-project-root pathnames there instead.

Is there some option to tell gcc to strip some part of pathname before emitting debug data? Or, maybe, there is some tool that could do that on compiled binaries?

I've tried using `SET(CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS ON)` (which seems to be [frowned upon](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/CMAKE-USE-RELATIVE-PATHS-td4042914.html) by devs) option, but as I'm using out-of-source builds, pathnames are still not in the form I'd want them to be. I.e. they're `./../src/mod_foo/foo.c` instead of `mod_foo/foo.c`.

Comment: `./../src/mod_foo/foo.c` is a **relative** path...

Comment: Yes, but not relative *to the project root*, though (which is at `./../src`)

Comment: Your have a problem with CMake, not with gcc. GCC puts into `.debug_str` exactly that it gets as a command line argument.

Comment: I don't really care about the method. I see three theoretically possible ways to do this, either of one is perfectly fine with me:

1) Making CMake change directory to project root and pass gcc relative-to-project-root source filename;
2) Changing this GCC behavior, so it'll mangle filenames before writing;
3) Patching the compiled binary with some tool, to fix filenames.

The problem is, I don't know how to do any of the above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the [RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE.html) property of a CMake target to have CMake invoke a shell script which transforms the source file path to a project relative path before invoking gcc. Use the CMake function [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) to generate a shell script which knows about the `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` and `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR` of your project.

In your outermost `CMakeLists.txt` add the following code:

```
configure_file(
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gcc_debug_fix.sh.in"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/gcc_debug_fix.sh"
    @ONLY)

add_executable (MyExecutable ...)

set_target_properties(MyExecutable PROPERTIES 
    RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/gcc_debug_fix.sh")
```

The following template shell script `gcc_debug_fix.sh.in` needs to go to the root directory of the CMake project:

```
#!/bin/sh

PROJECT_BINARY_DIR="@PROJECT_BINARY_DIR@"
PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR="@PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR@"

# shell script invoked with the following arguments
# $(CXX) $(CXX_DEFINES) $(CXX_FLAGS) -o OBJECT_FILE -c SOURCE_FILE

# extract parameters
SOURCE_FILE="${@: -1:1}"
OBJECT_FILE="${@: -3:1}"
COMPILER_AND_FLAGS=${@:1:$#-4}

# make source file path relative to project source dir
SOURCE_FILE_RELATIVE="${SOURCE_FILE:${#PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} + 1}"

# make object file path absolute
OBJECT_FILE_ABSOLUTE="$PROJECT_BINARY_DIR/$OBJECT_FILE"

cd "$PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR"

# invoke compiler
exec $COMPILER_AND_FLAGS -c "${SOURCE_FILE_RELATIVE}" -o "${OBJECT_FILE_ABSOLUTE}"
```

The shell script uses the information from the variables `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR` and `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` to transform the path of the source file to a path relative to the project root and the object file's path to an absolute path. Because gcc gets passed a project relative path now, `.debug_str` should use that path, too.

The following caveats apply:

- Be sure to set the executable bit of `gcc_debug_fix.sh.in`.
- For the script to work `CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS` has to set to `OFF` again.
- The script makes assumptions about the location of the file paths on the command line. This may not work if CMake uses a different rule to invoke the compiler. A more robust solution would be to scan the script arguments for the `-o` and `-c` flags.

Answer (score 31):

You can use the **-fdebug-prefix-map** flag to remap the debugging information paths. For example, to make the paths relative to the build location use: **-fdebug-prefix-map=/full/build/path=.**

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is much less complicated and brittle than sakra's answer.
Also of note is the `-ffile-prefix-map` flag, since `-fdebug-prefix-map` doesn't affect things such as the `__FILE__` macro.

Answer (score 1):

If I really couldn't fix the make file/tool to do this properly, I would write a wrapper script for gcc that recognises absolute pathnames and converts then to relative ones.

It might look something like this in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

out=()
for arg; do
  out=("${out[@]}" $(echo "$arg" | sed 's:/my/absolute/directory/:../:'))
done

exec gcc "${out[@]}"
```

If your source directory has subdirectories then you'll need to handle those carefully, but the above should work for a flat source directory. I've not tested it though, and I wouldn't be surprised if I've got the quoting wrong, but that'll only be a problem if you have pathnames with spaces in. It also doesn't handle parameters like `-I/whatever/include`, but you can fix that.