# CMake how to remove the path from compile errors

Tags: path, compiler-errors, g++, cmake

When using cmake if there is a compile error the error is output with the entire path to the file containing the error. This path can be very long (see example below) so often it word wraps and makes it difficult to read.

Example Output:

```
/home/nick/projects/projectA/src/environment/base/terrain/base/TestFile.h:21:37: error: ‘TestFile’ does not name a type
/home/nick/projects/projectA/src/environment/base/terrain/base/TestFile.h:21:54: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘test’
/home/nick/projects/projectA/src/environment/base/terrain/base/TestFile.h:21:54: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘test’
```

Is there a way to remove the path from the error?
Something like this:

```
TestFile.h:21:37: error: ‘TestFile’ does not name a type
TestFile.h:21:54: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘test’
TestFile.h:21:54: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘test’
```

Thanks

Comment: Use a custom `RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE` launcher. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607155/make-gcc-put-relative-filenames-in-debug-information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible within cmake, but you can always redirect stderr to stdout and filter the output with a short sed script. At least the common project path can be filtered

```
make 2>&1 | sed 's/\/home\/nick\/projects\/projectA\/src\///g'
```