# Improving the ccache hit rate

Tags: c++, ccache, distcc

I am working with distcc and ccache to speed up the compilation of my project.

I noticed that I am not getting any hits when I am building the same code from different directories. I looked up online https://github.com/ccache/ccache/issues/212 and saw that I need to set the `hash_dir flag = false`. I already have the variable `CCACHE_NOHASHDIR=true`. Am I missing something? Do I need to set/unset any other variables?

Answer (score 2):

Does your command line contain absolute paths? If so, you need to set `CCACHE_BASEDIR` to the base directory of your working copy. See *[How do I make ccache cache compilation when using absolute paths to the compiled files in different directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008642/how-do-i-make-ccache-cache-compilation-when-using-absolute-paths-to-the-compiled)*.

I wrote *[ccache quick guide](https://cppisland.wordpress.com/2018/12/30/ccache-quick-guide/)* which explains how to debug and avoid cache misses.

Comment: Thanks! I confirm that adding `export CCACHE_BASEDIR=$PWD` before my build do make cache hits.